# Error in some characters for convert from utf8 to latin1

Tags: c#, text, unicode, persian

I use below code for convert UTF8 (Persian characters) to LATIN1.

but it doesn't work for some character like (و  ی  ه)

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(source);
string des = iso.GetString(utfBytes);
```

Comment: Yes, the latin1 character set does not fully support persian characters, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: for example "تستی" convert to "تست�?"

Comment: @SajjadZare: Do you mean that you actually want to get `�` for unsupported characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use below code for convert UTF8 (Persian characters) to LATIN1.

ISO-8859-1 cannot contain Persian characters. What you are doing is intentionally making a [mojibake](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) error.

If your code is doing something functional, that implies that there is some other component taking the output from `des` and handling it incorrectly (ie outputting it as a Latin-like encoding when it should originally have been using UTF-8). If you can at all, it would be much better to fix that problem downstream, instead of trying to work around it with deliberately-bad encoding.

If you really have to handle it this way, and some characters work but others don't, the likelihood is that Latin-like encoding you are trying to target is not actually real Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1); the most likely reason for that is that it is Windows code page 1252. This shares many of the same character mappings as ISO-8859-1, but not all. So try `GetEncoding(1252)`.

Answer (score 0):

Latin1 is more orientated to the Latin Alphabeth (which is fine if you only aim to that) and UTF8 can represent **any** Unicode charset, not just Wester European countries, but also Eastern europeans. 
Most of the characters are the same but there are some differences. Take a look at the charsets of [UTF8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) and [Latin1](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html#ISO).